# Разница поведения макроса в зависимости от компилятора

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, vc++2015

Данный макрос работает без ошибок под компилятором `g++`

```
#define ASSIGN_VAR_RN(var, size, buf) \
({\
    for (int i = sizeof(var) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {\
        var |= buf[i]; \
        if (i != 0) \
            var <<= 8; \
        size++;\
    }\
})
```

Но выдает следующие ошибки, если попробовать запустить под `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler`

```
source_file.cpp(34): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
source_file.cpp(34): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
source_file.cpp(34): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

Функция запуска выглядит следующим образом

```
int main()
{
    char a[] = "hello world";
    int b = 0;
    int size = 0;
    ASSIGN_VAR_RN(b, size, a);   // строка 34 с ошибками выше
    std::cout << std::hex << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: А зачем наружные круглые скобки? Как должно компилироваться ваше `({ for(;;).... })`?

Comment: Видимо MS не понимает блок внутри выражения (круглых скобок). Просто уберите их

Comment: @avp сработало... Я вроде пытался так сделать, но почему-то не запускалось, магия какая-то...

Comment: @Harry по шаблону делал, отсутствие скобок действительно решает проблему )

Comment: @ЕгорФилатов, лучше переходите на правильную сторону (и проблем будет меньше)

Comment: @avp А такое вообще стандарту соответствует? `({....})`?

Comment: @Harry, а какая разница, если люди, пишущие на GNU (основная масса свободного софта) это используют?

Comment: @Harry Не соответствует.

Comment: GCC с флажками `-std=c++?? -pedantic-errors` не принимает такое.

Comment: Зачем тут макрос? `::std::memcpy(&b, a, sizeof(b));`

Comment: @avp Просто вы так выразились - "MS не понимает блок внутри выражения (круглых скобок)", что это выглядело как "очередная ошибка в поделке от MS". Вот я и заинтересовался...

Comment: @Harry, конечно, это не ошибка MS, несовместимость с нестандандартными расширениями наиболее распространенного компилятора это их стратегия.